# Stop service without error "Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid"

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services

I have WIndows Service app and want to stop service when main code is executed. I am trying to execute ServiceBase.Stop() in OnStart event, everything works fine, the service is stopped but I get annoying error message in event viewer

```
"Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid"
```

Any ideas how to stop windows service without errors?

```
 public partial class VirtualServerInitService : ServiceBase
    {

        public ILogger EventLogger = new EventLogger();

        public VirtualServerInitService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {            
            EventLogger.Write("Starting service!");
            new VirtualServerInit(EventLogger).Run();
            EventLogger.Write("VirtualServerInit code was executed");            
            Stop();//This code works and also gives error in event viewer
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            EventLogger.Write("Stopping service!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just return from the `OnStart` method and, if there are no more foreground threads running in your process, the process will exit and the service will be considered to be stopped. There's no need to call `Stop` on it.

Comment: Your `OnStart` should complete to let the SCM know that you successfully started. *Then* do your work. A service should not 'Stop' itself after the work is done, it should sit and wait for more work. Only stop when the SCM asks you to stop.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The service do not stop automatically after OnStart code is executed!

Comment: It will if there aren't any other foreground threads running. Which suggests that `VirtualServerInit().Run()` is creating one or more threads - which are presumably meant to stick around for a while, in which case tearing down the service will stop it from doing its job.

Comment: @Tomas but it will be signaled as on  starting  state  as  the handle will be created after the OnStart is completely executed

Comment: E.g. if you create a new service and have completely empty `OnStart` and `OnStop` methods, and start it from the Services MMC you'll get the message "The service started and then stopped".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a thread to make sure the OnStart method finishes. The threadpool will put your workitem on the queue and once a thread it is available it will execute your `Run` method and then calls `Stop` on the service. By then the [windows service manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150(v=vs.85).aspx) already handled the succesful start of your service and hence no error will be sent to the Eventlog when `Stop` is called.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        EventLogger.Write("Starting service!");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _ => {
            new VirtualServerInit(EventLogger).Run();
            EventLogger.Write("VirtualServerInit code was executed");            
            this.Stop();
         });
     }
```

You might consider leaving the service running and use a CustomCommand to control if actual work needs to be done. For that you can override [`OnCustomCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and send a pre determined integer to ask the service to perform a particular task for example by calling `sc virtualsvc control 128` from the commandline.

```
protected virtual void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    switch(command)
    {
        case 128:
            new VirtualServerInit(EventLogger).Run();
            EventLogger.Write("VirtualServerInit code was executed");            
            // maybe keep state if this only can be run once
            break;
        default:
           EventLogger.Write(String.Format("Unknown control code:{0}", command));            
           break;
    }
}
```